# How ng-click and ng-class works in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have tabs like functionality which is done with angular code. I just want to how its working. When I am clicking li its execute select(datalist), also its execute isActive(datalist) and isActive1($index). So my question is ng-click execute all the function which are in used in same controller.

Also I notice that function are executing twice. Here is logs of isActive($index).

```
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zbjks9wy/1/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="sampleapp">
    <div ng-controller="samplecontoller" ng-init="showData()">

 <ul>
 <li class="paginationclass" ng-repeat="datalist in datalists" ng-click="select(datalist)" ng-class="{active: isActive(datalist)}">
 <div ng-class={active:isActive1($index)}>{{ datalist.name }} </div> 
 </li>
</ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**Angular**

```
var myapp = angular.module('sampleapp', [ ]);
myapp.controller('samplecontoller', function ($scope) {
$scope.showData = function( ){
     $scope.datalists = [
    { "name": "Read about angular"},
    {"name": "Read about knockout"},
    {"name": "Read about backbone"},
    {"name": "Read about jquery"},
    {"name": "Read about javascript"}
    ]
}

$scope.select= function(item) {
           $scope.selected = item; 
    };
$scope.isActive = function(item) {
           return $scope.selected === item;
    };

    $scope.isActive1 = function(index) {
    console.log(index)
           return $scope.sd === index;
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the `li`, `ng-click` is triggered, and that updates the state etc. It also triggers an Angular `$digest` cycle, which refreshes the page. Each time it works through the page, it needs to evaluate `ng-class` on your `div` and that causes the logging. Hope that helps.

Comment: I just use isActive1 for demonstrator purpose, I just wanted to know why ng-click on Li trigger isActive1

Comment: @amit Ah, OK I have updated my answer for you - hope that helps